# A Flash Of Unstyled Contend Appearing On Only One Page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, display

Below is the menu bar and javascript that I'm using to create a website. I've set it so that the flash of unstyled content doesn't appear. The code that I'm using to do this works well on every other page I've tested it on except for this one. This is a page with a fair number of photos and text on it, but that wouldn't affect the page to load ignoring the code I've put in, would it?

Does anyone have any solutions for fixing this flash of unstyled content? Also, does anyone know why the code I implemented doesn't work on only one page?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" charset="utf-8">
    
<body style="visibility: hidden;" onload="js_Load() background-color: white; font-family: sans-serif;">
    
<title>#</title>
      
<div class="page-wrap">
    
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>
<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="../../../../../Home_English.html">Home</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="../../../../../Blog_English.html">Blog</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="../../../../../About_English.html">About This Website</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="../../../../../Bibliography_English.html">Bibliography</a></li>            
        
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; position: inline;">
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Custom Google Search" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;">
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style="padding-left: 5px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 50px; display: inline-flex; justify-content: center;">
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html">    

</form>
</div>    

    
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() {
 window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:morikoboshi.com' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
        return false;
    }
 
</script>


<script>
 document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() {
 if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) {
 document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
  } else {
 document.body.style.overflow = "";
  }
} 
 
if(!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2)
{
    window.location.reload();
}
</script>
    
<script>
    
document.body.style.visibility='visible';
    
</script>

</ul>    
</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I suggest you look carefully at your code to first eliminate syntax and logic errors. (and put it through a validator). For example the attributes in the body tag - the onload value is not closed with a double quote in the right place and what are those CSS styles doing as part of that anyway? Also you have a script which runs making the body visible immediately - should that be in your function?

Comment: All I'd like to be able to do is have nothing show up until all the content has fully loaded. The code for that for whatever reason doesn't work as it should on this page. Any suggestions for how I could make that possible?

Comment: As I commented, you have some script which makes the body visible immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `document.body.style.visibility='visible'` into `js_Load`, or just run it onload.

However why is there `background-color: white; font-family: sans-serif;` in `body` onload?

**Edit**:
This is probably due to the position of the `js_Load` function and `document.body.style.visibility='visible'`. `document.body.style.visibility='visible'` has already run before `js_Load` is called.

Comment: Do you mean putting this line of code in the body? -> style="visibility: hidden;" onload="js_Load(document.body.style.visibility='visible') 

I tried that but it didn't work. 

The other code is what I've been using to style the page color and font.

Comment: I mean placing it into the onload of the body like `<body onload="document.body.style.visibility='visible'">`.

Comment: Also `background-color: white; font-family: sans-serif;` will not be applied if placed in the onload since onload is for javascript and css within will raise an error.

Comment: You have to create a separate style tag or file for that.

Comment: There seems to be some other problem with this page. The code that I originally set works well on all the other web pages I built except this one. I still got the same flash of unstyled content even after trying the code that you suggested. Any other ideas?

Comment: May you send the `js_Load()` function? Thanks.

Comment: What I'm currently using (css) -> "visibility: hidden;" onload="js_Load()   Javascript -> document.body.style.visibility='visible';

Comment: I have made some edits.

Comment: Also I would suggest choosing between camel case and kebab case.

Comment: Where would be the best place to put the js_load function?

Comment: Maybe place `document.body.style.visibility='visible'` after the last element from `js_Load` is loaded?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this code isn't getting rid of the flash of unstyled content as it does on the other pages I created. Would this have anything to do with lots of photos or text on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but you can try something like the code below.

The main logic is to just run the `onload="js_Load()"` function on a page load Event (when it is detected).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0;" charset="utf-8">
    
<body style="visibility: hidden;" onload="js_Load()" style="background-color: white; font-family: sans-serif;" >
    
<title>#</title>
      
<div class="page-wrap">
    
<div class="cp_cont">
<input id="cp_toggle03" type="checkbox"/>
<div class="cp_mobilebar">
<label for="cp_toggle03" class="cp_menuicon">
<span></span>
</label>
</div>
<label id="h-menu_black" class="cp_toggle03" for="cp_menuicon"></label>


<div id="body" class="noscroll"></div>
        
<header class="cp_offcm03">
        
<nav>
<ul style="text-align: center; margin-left: 210px; overflow: hidden;">
            
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="../../../../../Home_English.html">Home</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="../../../../../Blog_English.html">Blog</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="../../../../../About_English.html">About This Website</a></li>
<li style="border-bottom: .05px solid lightgray;"><a href="../../../../../Bibliography_English.html">Bibliography</a></li>            
        
<div class="searchbar"> 
            
<form id="frmSearch" class="search2" method="get" action="default.html" style=" padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center; position: inline;">
<input class="search2" id="txtSearch" type="text" placeholder="Custom Google Search" name="serach_bar" size="31" maxlength="255" value="" style="top: 185px; width: 180px; height: 26px;">
<input class="search1" type="submit" name="submition" value="Search" style="padding-left: 5px; top: 153px; height: 25px; width: 50px; display: inline-flex; justify-content: center;">
<input class="search2" type="hidden" name="sitesearch" value="default.html">    

</form>
</div>    


</ul>    
</nav>
</header>

</body>


<script type="text/javascript">


function js_Load() 
{ document.body.style.visibility='visible'; }

document.getElementById('frmSearch').onsubmit = function() 
{
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=site:morikoboshi.com' + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value;
    return false;
}
  
document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').onchange = function() 
{
    if (document.getElementById('cp_toggle03').checked) 
    { document.body.style.overflow = "hidden"; } 
    else { document.body.style.overflow = ""; }
} 
 
if(!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type == 2)
{
    window.location.reload();
}


</script>

</html>
```